# How to get object via name

Tags: python, object

Let's define class and three instance of our class

```
class Fruit():
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

apple = Fruit('apple', 'red')
plum = Fruit('plum ', 'blue')
apricot = Fruit('apricot', 'orange')
```

Now user input fruit name

```
user_input_fruit = sys.stdin.read() # user typing 'plum'
```

At this point I have string variable with value 'plum'.
Now I want get object, related to user input, something like

```
favorit_fruit = user_input_fruit
```

So that it become

```
>>>print type(favorit_fruit)
<type 'instance'>
>>>print favorit_fruit.name
plum
```

How I can do this?

## UPDATE

Solution

```
class Fruit():
    _dic = {}

    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self._dic[name] = self
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

apple = Fruit('apple', 'red')
plum = Fruit('plum', 'blue')
apricot = Fruit('apricot', 'orange')

fruit_string = 'plum'

favorit_fruit = Fruit._dic[fruit_string]

>>>print type(favorit_fruit)
<type 'instance'>
>>>print favorit_fruit.name
plum
```

Comment: `if favorit_fruit.name == 'plum':`. I believe this is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to maintain a dictionary of objects created. Like this:

```
obj_dict = {}
apple = Fruit('apple', 'red')
obj_dict['apple'] = apple
plum = Fruit('plum ', 'blue')
obj_dict['plum'] = plum
apricot = Fruit('apricot', 'orange')
obj_dict['apricot'] = apricot
```

And then when  you get the user input, you reference the dict and get the object.

```
>>>print type(obj_dict[favorit_fruit])
<type 'instance'>
>>>print obj_dict[favorit_fruit].name
plum
```

Comment: Thank you for idea of using "dict of instance". I updated my post with final solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'fruit' object is global, you can access it via

```
global()[favorit_fruit].name
```

If the 'fruit' is part of another object, you just use its namespace instead

```
fruitBowl[favorit_fruit].name
```

assuming:

```
fruitBowl.plum = Fruit('plum', 'blue')
```